# Use Leapmotion and Tensorflow simultaneously with Python on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since I have to use Leapmotion to capture image data and use model trained from Tensorflow to do the classification on my image data, I have to use them simultaneously with Python on Windows platform.

However, Leapmotion only supports Python2.7 and Tensorflow only supports Python3.6 on Windows. Is there any way that I can solve this conflict?

Of course, First capturing image data using a python2.7 program and then do prediction using a python3.6 program is not what I want. I want the capturing and predicting process can be in real time,

I will be really grateful if someone can help! Thank you all for replying this post!